# How to detect a request coming from desktop user agent in JavaScript or Ruby Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I detect if a particular request is coming from a desktop?

I've tried for this solution in JavaScript:

```
function isDesktop(){  
    var isTouchDevice = function() {  return window.screenX === 0 && 'ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window; };
    var isDesktop = !isTouchDevice() ? true : false;
    }
isDesktop();
```

It works but this is applicable for only touch and non-touch devices, whereas today's generation have touch laptops and screens.

Can anyone suggest some solution where we can appropriately detect desktops apart from all other devices??

Comment: even if the solution is in Ruby, will be highly appreciated...

Comment: How are you going to tell laptops apart from desktops? They run identical software. Browser ID strings are easy to change, so you can't trust that on any platform.

Comment: better question, why is this even relevant? Why should a desktop have a different experience than a laptop?

Comment: If you're doing something that affects the user's experience, why not explain why it's important and ask them what type of device they're on? Don't try to sense it via JavaScript.

Comment: first of all sorry for late reply, actually I have to redirect the user to specific URL based on the device he is using. That is the case. There is no different user experience just a redirection is to be decided. If strings are manipulated, that cant be controlled but atleast for default Browser ID strings it need to be identified

Comment: @theTinMan could u plz share your views

Comment: another useful question shut down by a know it all. thanks SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've  found a trick in ruby and that did its work. Am using `browser gem` which tells you whether the request devise is 'mobile`or`tablet`.

Am just negating the response and considering it as desktop if its not a mobile device and not a tablet device.

For more clarification here is the code snippet after installing the gem.
here is the [reference](http://rubydoc.info/gems/browser/0.2.1/frames)

> require "browser"
>
> browser = Browser.new(:ua => request.user_agent, :accept_language =>
>   "en-us")
>   if !browser.mobile? && !browser.tablet? 
>      @device = "desktop" 
>   end

Comment: if anyone finds more better solution, will accept that as an answer.

Comment: I wont go with you answer because if you explore Browser gem there are methods for tv?, consoles like xbox, ps etc. So your logic will fail in that scenario.

Comment: @AMBasra my logic was restricted to certain limit. You can give a generic answer. will go through and accept it.

Comment: gem 'device_detector'. This is better then Browser. I have explored it code also and replaced my Browser gem by this one.